# Desarrollar aplicación Windows embedded o Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c++, windows

Tengo una PDA Honeywell Dolphin 6000 con windows embedded ce, o windows mobile 6.5 professional, tengo un problema con la aplicación que uso en el trabajo, y es que si se desconfigura la hora, pueden fallar algunos procesos de la aplicación.

He intentado que la hora se actualice automáticamente, pero el S.O. en si, no me hace caso en el Network Time de la pda, ya que esta activado todo, pero no actualiza ni fecha ni hora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras investigar un poco encontré lo necesario para desarrollar esto y he conseguido realizar una aplicación de prueba.

```
VS2008, sdk windows mobile 6.5, y .net framework compact 3.5
```

Con esto instalado he podido compilar la aplicación y funciona, y buscando he visto que le sucede lo mismo de la hora a mas personas:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722247/how-to-sync-the-windows-mobile-time-with-a-server

He intentado usar eso, pero me dice que me falta el coredll.dll que no se de donde sacarlo, ademas me gustaría poner la aplicación a modo de "servicio" en segundo plano, o con un icono en el menu principal, que ya he visto que algunas aplicaciones lo tienen.

```
advertencia CS0626: El método, operador o descriptor de acceso 'UpdateTime.Form1.SetLocalTime(ref UpdateTime.Form1.SYSTEMTIME)' está marcado como externo y no tiene atributos. 
Agregue un atributo DllImport para especificar la implementación externa.

 error CS0103: El nombre 'LocalClockOffset' no existe en el contexto actual
```

Muchas gracias por su atención, espero me puedan dar algún consejo o idea.

Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes probar a obtener la hora del servidor usando `net time`, como se explica por ejemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472290/579895)

Comment: Oh, genial, como no encontraba nada por google, pensé que no había nada publicado, solo una pregunta, tendría que hacer algo en especial para que se lance en el inicio de la pda?

Comment: Lo siento, pero no tengo ninguna experiencia en windows embedded,asi que no lo se la verdad :)

Comment: Gracias igualmente, investigaré :P